# Enqueue in SQS FIFO through Lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, fifo, enqueue

Can we Enqueue in SQS FIFO through Lambda function?
if not what is the alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Please take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416890/cant-trigger-lambdas-on-sqs-fifo

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "Enqueue in SQS FIFO through Lambda function"? Are you wishing to send a message to an Amazon SQS queue from a Lambda function, or are you wanting to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a message is added to an SQS queue? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Yeah sure,it means that i wish to send a message to an AMAZON SQS queue from a Lambda function.can i achieve this instead of using kinesis/cloudwatch ?

Comment: **November 2019:** AWS Lambda now supports Lambda triggers. See: [AWS Lambda Supports Amazon SQS FIFO (First-In-First-Out) as an Event Source](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-amazon-sqs-fifo-event-source/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

Here is an [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues-getting-started-java.html).

This is a java example of showing you how to send messages to your FIFO queue.

Source: I'm currently using a lambda to add messages to my SQS FIFO Queue

Comment: You didn't provide the solution, just a link.